# How SUM work when the input is a range of rows?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, spreadsheet

In my spreadsheet I see this formula:

```
=SUM(INDEX($B$2:F, 1) : INDEX($B$2:F, 5))
```

as much as I understand `INDEX($B$2:F, 1)` return a range of cells from `B2` to `F2`, and `INDEX($B$2:F, 5)` returns the cells from `B6` to `F6` and that means in the `SUM` we have a range of rows (ranges, right?)

It just sums all the values from `B2` to `F6`. I just what to understand how `SUM` input is interpreted in this case. How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX($B$2:F, 1) : INDEX($B$2:F, 5)
```

is equivalent to

```
B2:F6
```

So...

```
SUM(INDEX($B$2:F, 1) : INDEX($B$2:F, 5))
```

is equivalent to

```
SUM(B2:F6)
```

This is true because if the input array for INDEX is a range, the output will be a range too. (Ranges are arrays that in addition to holding a collection of values, also hold the information of where those values are located)

So `INDEX(B2:F,1):INDEX(B2:F,5)` is equivalent to `B2:F2:B6:F6`, which is equivalent to `B2:F6`.

This is also the reason why we can do things like:

```
=A1:INDEX(A1:A,MAX(ROW(A1:A)*(A1:A<>"")))
```

To return all the values in column A until the last non-empty cell. It's because the INDEX function returns a range, for example, A1:A10, so the formula evaluates to

```
=A1:A1:A10
```

Which is equivalent to

```
=A1:A10
```

Some of the other functions that return ranges when ranges are provided are:

- XLOOKUP - if result_range is a range
- LOOKUP - if result_range is a range
- INDIRECT
- OFFSET

To check if the return value of a function is an array or a range, you can feed it to any function that only accepts ranges, such as ROW, COLUMN, OFFSET, CELL... If the function returns an error "Argument must be a range", then it means you have provided an array.

For example:

```
=ROW(INDEX(B2:F,1)) // 2
=ROW({INDEX(B2:F,1)}) // #N/A - not a range
```

Comment: Why is it equivalent to `B2:F6`?

Comment: I added more information in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The way I think ranges is as a rectangle with coordinates. It goes from the cell in the top-left to the cell in the bottom-right.

As you stated, the first INDEX will result in `B2:F2` , and the second in `B6:F6.` Which is the top-left cell? B2. Which is the bottom-right cell: F6. Then the rectangle goes `from B2 to F6`. The rows are "irrelevant" in this case

Comment: PS: as an experiment, you can try writing =SUM(F2:B6) and GS will transform it to =SUM(B2:F6)

Comment: Looks like you say that it just tries to figure out within many cells what is the top-left and right bottom. If that is so then in that case `=SUM({Z1,A1} : {B2, B3})` is equivalent to `=SUM(A1:B3)` ?